# Interview Programming question?(Long bit representation)?

Tags: java

Given a long number n, we need to return a long number which we get from the concatenation of binary representation from 1 to n?
Example say n=3, then answer would be 27, as 1 in binary is 01, 2 is 10 and 3 is 11 so concatenation would be 011011 which is 27.
this is the approach I used,

```
class Solution {
    static String[] arr;

    public static long binaryArray(long A) {
        String res = "";
        for (long i = 1; i <= A; i++) {
            res += toBinary(i);
        }

        long rest = toLong(res);
        return rest % 1000000007;

    }

    static long toLong(String s) {
        int a = s.length();
        int pow = 0;
        long res = 0;
        for (int i = a - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            char aa = s.charAt(i);
            long f = Character.getNumericValue(aa);
            long power = (long) Math.pow(2, pow);
            res += power * f;
            pow++;
        }
        return res;
    }

    static String toBinary(long a) {
        if (a == 0) {
            return "0";
        }
        String binary = "";
        binary = Long.toBinaryString(a);
        return binary;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        long n = 89900;
        arr = new String[(int) n + 1];
        arr[0] = "0";
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        long b = binaryArray(n);
        long endTime = System.nanoTime();
        long totalTime = endTime - startTime;
        long convert = TimeUnit.SECONDS.convert(totalTime, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
        System.out.println(convert);
        System.out.println(b);

    }
}
```

but it is not completing the request in the required time.
Is there a quicker way?

Comment: So you want to concatenate the binary representations from 1...89900 in a single thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public static long f(int n) {
    long n2 = ((long)n) << n;
    return n2 | n;
}
```

There is much irrelevant text in the specification: binary representation, concatenation and such. What is said:

- the bits of n should be "concatenated" n bits to the left = bit shift.

So this interview question was intentionally misleading, and the actual solution simple. It tried and succeeded to let the interviewee start with bit tests and such.

Now I am somewhat experienced and the trick is always to look at the whole picture,
think in notions like sets, or Integer's bit functions.

---

As @kaya3 commented, the following might be more correct.

```
public static long f(int n) {
    long n2 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        if ((n & (1 << i)) == 1) { // i'th bit set?
            int bits = 32 - Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(i);
            n2 <<= bits;
            n2 |= i;
        }
    }
    return n2;
}
```

Comment: @mwarren I was fast to save the solution first; the explanation I am still working on - the hard part.

Comment: For the input 4, the expression `(4 << 4) | 4` gives 1000100 in binary, but according to the question the result in binary ought to be either `1,10,11,100` or `001,010,011,100` (without the commas, of course). It's not clear whether leading zeros should count (or if so, how many of them).

Comment: @kaya3 I added a better implementation of the question. Though for 100 I think the 0 bits are skipped in the concatenation, also 01 is suspect (why always 2 bits for 3). If not skipped on 0, one could have one single concatenation ... 4 3 2 1, and take the bits from the right.

Comment: Based on the `% 1000000007` in the OP's code, I'm guessing it is required to work for larger values of `n`, possibly including values where the concatenation would exceed the range of a `long`. I think the question is too poorly specified to say for sure, though.

Comment: @kaya3 exactly, such an incomplete specification can either be a signal to run away from that dev team, or it is crafted just to see an approach and being able to give critical remarks afterwards. Whatever. One just should not "block" and should come up with a sufficiently smart solution.